# How do I sort this array of objects by the birth year of the individual objects?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object, superclass

[This is the Adult superclass which worker and manager extend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKhFP.png)

[This is my driver class which creates the arrays and sorts them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ehMK.png)

What I'm trying to do is sort the employees array in order of the worker object's birth years and the supervisors array in order of the manager object's names. I dont really know where to start and I would greatly appreciate some help on how to actually arrange the objects in order. Thanks!

Comment: check the 'Comparator' paragraph https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparable-vs-comparator-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your design you add the Worker instance to the engineers array. One thing you can do is use Map data structure in java.

```
SortedMap<Integer,String> sm = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
sm.put(bYear,name);
```

This will store a [key,value] pair in the map, in this case the index will be the Birth Years and the value will be Names. To iterate through the map, you have to use an iterator:

```
Iterator i = sm.iterator(); 
while(i.hasNext()){
     Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry)i.next(); 
     int key = (Integer)m.getKey(); 
     String value = (String)m.getValue();       
     System.out.println("Birth Year : " + key + "  Name : " + value); 
}
```

If you want to store the Worker object inside an array and still want them to be sorted, you have to check before adding and that would be a lot of work.

One more thing I want to mention, you shouldn't initalize the class parameters

```
protected int birthYear;
protected String name;
```

should be the way to use it. Hope this helps, happy coding.